# Get the value of a promise and assign to variable

Tags: node.js, promise

`utility.fetchInfo()` returns a Promise object. I need to be able to get the value of this Promise object and assign the value of it to a variable that I can then use later on in my code.

At the moment, I can happily print the value of `result` to the console, but I need to be able to assign this value to `myVal`. So far, I've tried a lot of things and nothing has worked.

`var myVal = utility.fetchInfo().then(result => console.log(result));`

Thanks

Comment: I think it is because the Promise resolve is asynchronous. I would use the async and await keywords. `const myVal = await utility.fetchInfo();` For this to work you have to add async to the function that contains this line: `async function funcName()`. This way the program will wait on the await line until the Promise is resolved and then continue.

Answer (score 11):

What @dhilt said but do your stuff inside the promise callback function:

```
utility.fetchInfo().then(result => { 
  doSomethingWith(result);
});
```

Or use async/await if you are using a recent version of Node or Babel:

```
async function myFunction () {
    var myVal = await utility.fetchInfo();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I will experiment with the async/wait option. I have things working by having moved all the necessary code within the callback function as suggested.

Comment: how to assigned the `result` inside the callback to a variable that was initialized before the fetch.  i.e. I want to do a lot more stuff with the response data.

Comment: @BrianWiley You can't do that cleanly. You have to do that stuff within the callback. If you don't like the nested nature of callbacks (known as callback hell) then use async/await.

Comment: Thanks, I have been reading about that.  I am coming from sending data frames from R Shiny world.  I am wondering if underneath they are handling with those 2 ways.

Answer (score 5):

Just do an assignment within the callback's body

```
utility.fetchInfo().then(result => { myVal = result; });
```

---

Depends on the situation, for example, if there's a big piece of async logic, it may be better to extract it in a separate function:

```
let myVal; // undefined until myAsyncFunc is called

const myAsyncFunc = (result) => { 
   console.log(result);
   myVal = result;
   // ...
};

utility.fetchInfo().then(myAsyncFunc); // async call of myAsyncFunc
```

Comment: I tried this, but when i go to use myVal further in my code, its value is `undefined`

Comment: It's because of async nature of the promise call. The code that uses a promise result must wait for this result. The simplest way is to move your code into the promise-success callback.

Comment: Ah so before I saw this, I moved all my code into the callback function and everything works. There is no issue with `undefined` now. Is this good practice or is async/wait "better"?

Comment: I originally thought that `undefined` was due to scoping issues, but clearly not and it's down to the async nature. Promises/callbacks and nodeJS are new to me :)

Comment: One way isn't really better than the other: it comes down to personal preference. I think most people who understand async/await would prefer it but it is a new feature so whether it is supported depends on the environment the code is running on.

Comment: Your question is a part of holy war between the functional (promises) and the imperative (async/await) paradigms. I vote for promises... If you came from imperative world (for example C, Java etc), then maybe it would be simpler for you to use async/await...

Comment: RE: promise version, does it make more sense to pre-set the code with let before this promise occurs? Or should the myVal be a new 'var' keyword? @dhilt

Comment: @craft I've updated the answer a bit, hope it helps.

Comment: @dhilt that's perfect and pretty much what I've been doing. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 1):

When you return the value to another file/function and you are getting undefined because another function where you are using that value is not waiting for the value to be assigned to the variable. For example there are two function

```
function1(){
   var x=desired_value
}

function2(){
   var y = x
}
```

now function1 might take some time to assign desire value to var x and java script ll not wait for this, it ll start running function2 and when you read the value of y you will get undefined.

To solve this problem we can use java script promise/await/async, return value from async function as resolve. refer below example

```
async function1(){  //function1 should be async here for this to work
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
       resolve(desired_value)
});
}
```

or above function can be writtern as

```
 async function1(){  //function1 should be async here for this to work

        return Promise.resolve(desired_value)
    }
```

Now we can use this value in another function by calling the function1 and use await keyword

```
function2(){
   var y = await function1();
}
```

now it ll wait for function1 to complete before assigning its value to y.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is some fancy ES7 syntax:

```js
var myVal = (async () => {
    var data = await utility.fetchInfo();
    return data;
})();

(async () => {
    console.log(await myVal);
})();
```

Keep in mind `console.log(myVal)` will end up with `Promise { <pending> }`, So instead you would use

```js
(async () => {
    console.log(await myVal);
})();
```

which would return your desired output.

Comment: 1. the bottom example of code repeats the 2nd part of the top example.
2. So I was not surprised that it did not work.