# How to return the value from inner function in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have Nodejs code using request library to get the authentication token from a url.

```
var request = require("request")

const wellish_dev_url = "https://dev.wellish.com"

function get_auth_token(){
    const  api_end_point = wellish_dev_url + "/api/v1/auth"

    var options = {
        url: api_end_point,
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        auth: {
            'user': 'admin',
            'pass': 'password'}
    }

    var r = request.get(options, function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode==200){
            var token = JSON.parse(body)
            var auth_token = token["data"][0]["accessToken"]
            // console.log(auth_token)
            return auth_token
        }
        else{
            console.log("Code : " + response.statusCode)
            console.log("error : " + error)
            console.log('body : ' + body)
        }
    })
}

// get_auth_token()
var auth_token_new = get_auth_token()
console.log(auth_token_new)
```

I want to return the `auth_token` to be used as an argument in another function. However, it shows undefined.

I look up online to use `cb`, however, I have no idea how it works. I really want to return the value without using `cb`. Any helps?

Comment: `cb` simply means `callback` - and it works like any other callback would

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Can I do it without using cb?

Comment: I suggest to return a Promise from your function, and resolve it in the inner callback, I can provide an answer with an example if that can help

Comment: @jo_va Or you could refer to the proposed duplicate since it pretty much covers every possible topic with respect to asynchronous code in JavaScript.

Comment: @zero298, you are totally right indeed.

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/247483/9180019) question/answer useful, since the solution does not include promises _per se_ - good old _XHR_, however in terms of a long run I strongly suggest to get familiar with _promises_, then _async/await_ - (as a 'bonus' feature they simplify life a lot ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback is only executed once the response comes back from the server. By that time, your function will already have been executed.

Since your code is asynchronous, you need a means to return the response only when you get it back from the server.

You can use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for that task.

Here is an example on how to solve it in your particular case. Use the Promise constructor to return a Promise which resolves/rejects when your inner callback gets called.

Then you simply have to chain a `.then()` to your function call to get the token:

```
...

function get_auth_token() {
    const  api_end_point = ...
    const options = ...

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var r = request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                var token = JSON.parse(body)
                var auth_token = token["data"][0]["accessToken"]
                resolve(auth_token)
            } else {
                console.log("Code : " + response.statusCode)
                console.log("error : " + error)
                console.log('body : ' + body)
                reject(error)
            }
        })
    });
}

get_auth_token()
    .then(token => console.log(token))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

You can also use `await` to get the value from the Promise like this, just make sure you are using `await` in a function marked `async`:

```
async function parent_function() {
    function get_auth_token() { ... }

    try {
        const token = await get_auth_token();
        console.log(token);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am very new to Nodejs, and I have no idea we have to use Promise and callback, I just want to return the value simply like how python does. Is there any way to return without using Promise and callback

Comment: @Akira, your callback is executed later in time, once a response comes back from the server. So the code is inherently asynchronous. Your function will be done executing before the response from the server will come, so you need a means to execute your code only once this response comes back, you can use a Promise for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have used Python before, so why don't we consider the async using python? Every time I want to return some value using Nodejs, I need to consider the async/sync, right?

Comment: @Akira, yes, but most libraries in JavaScript will already return you a Promise, if they don't you can use the above trick to return a Promise from which you can access the value when it becomes available

Comment: I think your solution works, one more question, how can I assign a new variable to the value returned from the function? I have tried the `var auth_token_new = get_auth_token().then(token => console.log(token))` However, it also print out additional stuff which I don't want `Promise{<pending>}`

Comment: While using both `resolve` and `reject` it would be nice to provide a line responsible for handling the second one as well, e.g:  
`get_auth_token().then(console.log).catch(console.log)`  
or
`get_auth_token().then(result => {
console.log(result)
}).catch(error => {
console.log(error)
})`  
they both result's are the same in this case. To avoid confusion stick to the second example (first is for OP's further research ;)).

Comment: @Akira, if you want to get the value with an assignment, I suggest to use async/await, otherwise, you will have to access the value from within `.then(...)`, what you are getting is the raw value of the Promise and not the "resolved" value

Comment: @the0ffh Thanks for the input, I am just wondering whether or not I can assign a new variable for that

Comment: @jo_va could you provide an example using async/ await? I still don't understand why we cannot assign a new variable using Promise, since my goal is to return the value first, then assign it to a variable, then use that variable as argument in the other functions

Comment: @Akira, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355664/get-the-value-of-a-promise-and-assign-to-variable/46355826) - the answer describes how can you assign results of `promise` / `async/await` using example provided by @jo_va

Comment: @Akira, I suggest you read some material on Promise. This was already explained, using `.then` and `async/await`, see my updated answer.

Comment: let say you have a following promise: `let test = (param) => Promise ((resolve, reject)=> ...bla,bla...)` to operate on it's return values, you have to do the following: `test.then(returnValue => {let myVariable = returnValue; console.log(myVariable)}).catch(error => {console.log(error)})`  
+ as @jo_va suggested, read _MDN docs_ regarding _promises_ ie.  google -> _mdn promises_